# Responsive table via CSS

Tags: html, css

I want to display an input element with a button to the right of it, such that the width of the input element plus a small gap plus the width of the button occupies the entire width of the container. This smells like a job for a table.

My basic CSS and HTML are like this:

```css
.css-table {
  display: table;
}

.css-tr {
  display: table-row;
}

.css-td {
  display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<div class='css-table'>
  <div class='css-tr'>
    <div class='css-td'>
      <input />
    </div>
    <div class='css-td'>
      <button>Do it</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

So, what CSS styling can I use so that the table is the full width of its container, with the button right-justified (against the right edge of the container) and the input element occupying the remaining space to the left of the button (with a small gap between the right edge of the input element and the left edge of the button)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This only looks like a job for a table if you are still stuck in 1990. ;) If you want a modern, more up to date solution you should look into flexbox for one dimensional layouts. css-tricks has a [good overview on flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/), but there are also a ton of other resources on the web to get you started.

Edit:
Saw that you wanted a small gap between the right edge of the input element and the left edge of the button, added it to the snippet.

```css
.css-row {
  display: flex;
}

.css-row input {
  flex-grow: 1;
  margin-right: 5px; /* to set the space for the button */
}
```

```html
<div class='css-row'>
  <input />
  <button>Do it</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks in particular for the link to the flexbox overview. That's really helpful! Guess it's time to leave the '90s behind (but I'm afraid I'm stuck with the new and improved shaggy 2020 hair).

Answer (score 3):

Hope these could work.

```css
.css-table {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}

.css-tr {
    display: table-row;
}

.css-td {
    display: table-cell;
}

.css-td input{
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class='css-table'>
    <div class='css-tr'>
        <div class='css-td'>
            <input type="text"/>
        </div>
        <div class='css-td'>
            <button>Do it</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How did you get the "Run code snippet" magic attached to your answer?

Comment: @Bob.at.Indigo.Health if you see there is a icon " < > " so you just have to click there and add CSS and HTML in respective places and add. that should do.

Comment: Oh.... I just noticed that my original post magically gained a "Run code snippet" button. Apparently, StackOverflow has a new trick... it seems to be able to find HTML and CSS in marked code blocks and put them together so they can be "run".

Comment: This was not done via magic, I just edited your question. Sorry to disappoint you :-D You can see this if you click the "edited ..." link under your post.